# C# + XPath поиск элемента

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Второй день бьюсь с парсингом xml с помощью XPath, прошу помощи.

Есть исходный xml файл:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:getDocSaleListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://services.ru/">
      <ns2:list>
        <ns2:nsaID>100397431</ns2:nsaID>
        <ns2:id>7785846</ns2:id>
        <ns2:shiftID>89800</ns2:shiftID>
        <ns2:docDate>2020-08-02T23:49:43.961+03:00</ns2:docDate>
        <ns2:docNo>7785846</ns2:docNo>
        <ns2:entityCreator>STATION</ns2:entityCreator>
        <ns2:userName>Швабра</ns2:userName>
        <ns2:dateDef>2020-10-02T03:00:06.539+03:00</ns2:dateDef>
        <ns2:direction>NORMAL_DIRECTION</ns2:direction>
        <ns2:goodsDetails>
          <ns2:articleID>9990000001562</ns2:articleID>
          <ns2:azsID>100397431</ns2:azsID>
          <ns2:id>84514</ns2:id>
          <ns2:shiftID>89800</ns2:shiftID>
          <ns2:barcode>46214829</ns2:barcode>
          <ns2:basePrice>113.00</ns2:basePrice>
          <ns2:baseSum>113.00</ns2:baseSum>
          <ns2:dmcode>00000046214829uD&amp;Y&lt;7?AB9UFb/p</ns2:dmcode>
          <ns2:hostname>mksrv1</ns2:hostname>
          <ns2:multiplier>1</ns2:multiplier>
          <ns2:position>1</ns2:position>
          <ns2:quantity>1.000</ns2:quantity>
          <ns2:serialNumber>0327260006003759</ns2:serialNumber>
          <ns2:tradePrice>113.00</ns2:tradePrice>
          <ns2:tradeSum>113.00</ns2:tradeSum>
          <ns2:unitName>шт</ns2:unitName>
          <ns2:wdChunkSum>0.00</ns2:wdChunkSum>
        </ns2:goodsDetails>
        <ns2:hostName>mksrv1</ns2:hostName>
        <ns2:loyalityTerminalID>0</ns2:loyalityTerminalID>
        <ns2:loyaltyProcessingID>888</ns2:loyaltyProcessingID>
        <ns2:loyatyCardNumber/>
        <ns2:motherSale>0</ns2:motherSale>
        <ns2:motherSaleStateID>0</ns2:motherSaleStateID>
        <ns2:motherShiftID>0</ns2:motherShiftID>
        <ns2:payCardNo/>
        <ns2:payState>TRANSPAYSTATE_DONE</ns2:payState>
        <ns2:payTime>TRANSPAYTIME_PREPAY</ns2:payTime>
        <ns2:paymentProcessingID>100</ns2:paymentProcessingID>
        <ns2:paymentTerminalID>0</ns2:paymentTerminalID>
        <ns2:prevSaleStateId>0</ns2:prevSaleStateId>
        <ns2:saleBornSource>SALEBORNSOURCE_OPERATOR</ns2:saleBornSource>
        <ns2:saleID>7785790</ns2:saleID>
        <ns2:saleState>TRANS_ST_EXECUTED</ns2:saleState>
        <ns2:wholeDiscount>0.00</ns2:wholeDiscount>
      </ns2:list>
    </ns2:getDocSaleListResponse>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

блоков `ns2:list` может быть несколько

Получаем их

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(result);
XmlElement xRoot = xml.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList items = xml.GetElementsByTagName("ns2:list");
XmlNamespaceManager xs = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
xs.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
```

Далее пытаемся вытащить вложенные ноды

```
foreach (XmlNode cx in items)
{
    string docDate = cx.SelectSingleNode("ns2:docDate").InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine(docDate);
}
```

Как я только не пытался, ни как не могу получить значение параметров.
Если я вместо имени ноды ставлю `"*"`,  тогда возвращается полный список вложенных нод. По имени искать не хочет. Подскажите в чем причина.

Comment: У вас есть WSDL (или ASMX)? Сгенерировать по нему набор классов и работать с их помощью, без ручного кодинга.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У вас не правильно указан namespace вместо http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ надо http://services.ru/
2. Что бы заработал SelectSingleNode нужно передать в него XmlNamespaceManager

Итого:

```
var sampleXml = @"
     <S:Envelope xmlns:S=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
       <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
       <S:Body>
          <ns2:getDocSaleListResponse xmlns:ns2=""http://services.ru/"">
             <ns2:list>
                <ns2:nsaID>100397431</ns2:nsaID>
                <ns2:id>7785846</ns2:id>
                <ns2:shiftID>89800</ns2:shiftID>
                <ns2:docDate>2020-08-02T23:49:43.961+03:00</ns2:docDate>
             </ns2:list>
             <ns2:list>
                <ns2:nsaID>100397431</ns2:nsaID>
                <ns2:id>7785846</ns2:id>
                <ns2:shiftID>89800</ns2:shiftID>
                <ns2:docDate>2020-08-02T23:49:43.961+03:00</ns2:docDate>
             </ns2:list>
       </ns2:getDocSaleListResponse>
       </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
";

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(sampleXml);

XmlNamespaceManager xnsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
xnsm.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://services.ru/");

XmlNodeList items = xml.GetElementsByTagName("ns2:list");

foreach (XmlNode cx in items) {
    var docDateNode = cx.SelectSingleNode("ns2:docDate", xnsm);
    string docDateValue = docDateNode.InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine(docDateValue);
}
```

Comment: 1 пункт исправил.  2. Тоже так пробовал. По итогу все равно NullReferenceException

Comment: Ну код который я привел, я проверил... Попробуйте его скопировать или приведите свой минимальный пример(без него трудно что то советовать)

Comment: У меня все точно так же как у вас. И ваш код вижу что работает. А вот у меня не работает) в онлайн XPath тестере тоже проверяю свою выборку.... работает.Какая то мистика. Попробую входной xml  файл проверить, так как все остальное одинаковое в нашем коде. Большое спасибо вам. Теперь я точно уверен что делал все верно.